# Persian OCR issue

Tags: ocr

I'm currently working on OCR (for Persian language),
althougth the "fas.traineddata" is avaliable in the tessdata, but when I use the following command, nothing happends:

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('image.png'), lang='fas'))
```

image:
[image: character image]

and also I've used traineddata of https://github.com/reza1615/PersianOcr but again no result.

what should I do?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code on my image in Persian and the result was complete. did you already install tesseract-ocr-fas? if not:

```
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr-fas
```